# Estimate missing values in spark but with specific conditions on sum of estimated values

Tags: apache-spark, conditional-statements, missing-data

I have a problem in spark (pyspark). I need to estimate missing data, but I have to respect certain conditions. I've reproduced an example below to explain the problem:

1. Creation of the dataframe :

```
data = [{"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":1, "Heure": 1, "Value": 2400.000},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":1, "Heure": 2, "Value": 2400.171},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":1, "Heure": 3, "Value": None},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":1, "Heure": 4, "Value": 2401.853},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":2, "Heure": 1, "Value": 2402.155},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":2, "Heure": 2, "Value": 2402.725},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":2, "Heure": 3, "Value": 2403.001},
        {"Identifiant": 'A',"Jour":2, "Heure": 4, "Value": 2403.254},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":1, "Heure": 1, "Value": 1200.000},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":1, "Heure": 2, "Value": 1200.125},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":1, "Heure": 3, "Value": 1200.243},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":1, "Heure": 4, "Value": 1200.586},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":2, "Heure": 1, "Value": 1201.686},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":2, "Heure": 2, "Value": None},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":2, "Heure": 3, "Value": None},
        {"Identifiant": 'B',"Jour":2, "Heure": 4, "Value": 1202.624},      
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

+-----+-----------+----+--------+
|Heure|Identifiant|Jour|   Value|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+
|    1|          A|   1|  2400.0|
|    2|          A|   1|2400.171|
|    3|          A|   1|    null|
|    4|          A|   1|2401.853|
|    1|          A|   2|2402.155|
|    2|          A|   2|2402.725|
|    3|          A|   2|2403.001|
|    4|          A|   2|2403.254|
|    1|          B|   1|  1200.0|
|    2|          B|   1|1200.125|
|    3|          B|   1|1200.243|
|    4|          B|   1|1200.586|
|    1|          B|   2|1201.686|
|    2|          B|   2|    null|
|    3|          B|   2|    null|
|    4|          B|   2|1202.624|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+
```

2. Calculation of the consumption (difference between current row and next row - specific for each Identifiant (A and B) :

```
window = Window.partitionBy("Identifiant").orderBy(["Jour",'Heure'])

df = df.withColumn("Value_Energy", F.lead(F.col("Value")).over(window) - F.col("Value"))

+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+
|Heure|Identifiant|Jour|   Value|       Value_Energy|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+
|    1|          B|   1|  1200.0|              0.125|
|    2|          B|   1|1200.125|0.11799999999993815|
|    3|          B|   1|1200.243| 0.3430000000000746|
|    4|          B|   1|1200.586|  1.099999999999909|
|    1|          B|   2|1201.686|               null|
|    2|          B|   2|    null|               null|
|    3|          B|   2|    null|               null|
|    4|          B|   2|1202.624|               null|
|    1|          A|   1|  2400.0|0.17099999999982174|
|    2|          A|   1|2400.171|               null|
|    3|          A|   1|    null|               null|
|    4|          A|   1|2401.853| 0.3020000000001346|
|    1|          A|   2|2402.155|  0.569999999999709|
|    2|          A|   2|2402.725| 0.2760000000002947|
|    3|          A|   2|2403.001| 0.2529999999997017|
|    4|          A|   2|2403.254|               null|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+
```

3. Estimation of the NaN consumptions (because of missing Value in the df), specific for each Identifiant and with a mean different for each Heure.

```
window = Window.partitionBy(["Identifiant", "Heure"]).orderBy(["Identifiant"])

df = df.withColumn("Value_Energy_AVG", F.avg("Value_Energy").over(window))

df = df.sort(col("Identifiant"),col("Jour"), col('Heure'))

+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|Heure|Identifiant|Jour|   Value|       Value_Energy|   Value_Energy_AVG|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+-------------------+
|    1|          A|   1|  2400.0|0.17099999999982174|0.37049999999976535|
|    2|          A|   1|2400.171|               null| 0.2760000000002947|
|    3|          A|   1|    null|               null| 0.2529999999997017|
|    4|          A|   1|2401.853| 0.3020000000001346| 0.3020000000001346|
|    1|          A|   2|2402.155|  0.569999999999709|0.37049999999976535|
|    2|          A|   2|2402.725| 0.2760000000002947| 0.2760000000002947|
|    3|          A|   2|2403.001| 0.2529999999997017| 0.2529999999997017|
|    4|          A|   2|2403.254|               null| 0.3020000000001346|
|    1|          B|   1|  1200.0|              0.125|              0.125|
|    2|          B|   1|1200.125|0.11799999999993815|0.11799999999993815|
|    3|          B|   1|1200.243| 0.3430000000000746| 0.3430000000000746|
|    4|          B|   1|1200.586|  1.099999999999909|  1.099999999999909|
|    1|          B|   2|1201.686|               null|              0.125|
|    2|          B|   2|    null|               null|0.11799999999993815|
|    3|          B|   2|    null|               null| 0.3430000000000746|
|    4|          B|   2|1202.624|               null|  1.099999999999909|
+-----+-----------+----+--------+-------------------+-------------------
```

4. The problem : the difference of consumption between the Value 1202.624 (Identifiant B - Jour 2 - Heure 4) and the Value 1201.686 (Identifiant B - Jour 2 - Heure 1) is 0.938. And when I do the sum of respective mean values_consumption corresponding to these value (0.125 + 0.118 + 0.343) i have 0.586. So a possibility is to correct these mean values with, for example, a ratio like 0.125 * (0.586/0.938). But how can I do this in an optimized way?

Thanks a lot.

I can do the correction in pandas with numpy and array with iterations, but I would like to do in spark with the best code.

Comment: Hi All, anyone have any ideas?